# Building the GLUI2 Library (Ubuntu)

Tags: c++, linux, opengl, glui

I'm attempting to install [the GLUI2 library](https://code.google.com/p/glui2/).

I'm following the directions in the ReadMe which tells me to go GLUI's root directory and run Make. 
I get the following error :

```
/usr/bin/ld: Glui2/stb_image.o: relocation R_X86_64_32 against `.data' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
```

I tried including -fPIC in both compile lines in the makefile, and I get this error message:

```
/usr/bin/ld: Glui2/g2Button.o: relocation R_X86_64_32S against `_ZTV8g2Button' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
Glui2/g2Button.o: error adding symbols: Bad value
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I really have no idea what these errors are telling me or what I should do to resolve them.

I'm using it to build a small UI for a game I'm making in OpenGL, if you'd suggest a different library which works with GLUT, I'd appreciate those suggestions too...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Glui2/stb_image.o is built from Glui2/stb_image.c file. Rename the file to Glui2/stb_image.**cpp**, and update the file name in makefile.

Then run "make clean" and again "make".

It worked for me, it seems that mixing c and cpp files doesn't work out well in this project.